# Patterns for HTTP endpoint Lambda calling other Lambdas and returning value to user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway

i have a question about lambda anti patterns, and how to address my specific situation.

My current setup is this:

user/webpage -> ApiGateway -> Lambda1 -> synchronously calls Lambda2 (my other microservice) -> back to lambda1 -> back to user

Currently my lambda2 is behind an apigateway as well, but I toyed with idea of invoking directly.  Either way it's basically another microservice that I control.

I understand that generally, lambdas calling other lambdas are considered an antipattern.  All the blogs/threads/etc online mention using stepfunctions instead, or sqs, or something else.

In my situation, I don't see how I could use stepfunctions, since I have to return something to the webpage/user.  If I used a stepfunction, it seems like I would have to then poll for the results, or maybe use websockets; basically in my webpage I would not be able to just call my endpoint and get a result, I'd have to have some way to asynchronously get my result.

Similarly with a queue, or any other solution I saw online, it's basically all asynchronous.

Is there any other pattern or way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While invoking a lambda from another lambda, everything will work fine except when the second lambda timeouts or it throttles. If your business logic is built in such a way that failures are handled gracefully and has idempotent behaviour built in, then a lambda calling another lambda (via API gateway or direct invocation) should work fine. Having said that, AWS has come out with [Synchronous Express Workflows for AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/). The linked blog has detailed examples of using it. The only caveat here is that your entire operation should get over in 5 minutes. The maximum duration an express workflow can run is 5min. So if your application flow is completing within that time limit then this is the recommended way of orchestrating services.